# Definite Integration ( a little query)

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

### $$\int_0^π \frac{xdx}{a^2\cos^2x+b^2\sin^2x} \,dx$$

Using property
$$\int_a^b f(x) \,dx= \int_a^b f(a+b-x) \,dx$$
(i can't write it correctly,please check it)

I get, $2I=\pi\int_0^\pi \frac{dx}{a^2\cos^2x+b^2\sin^2x} \,dx$

On dividing numerator and denominator of R.H.S by $\cos^2x$
I get, $2I=\pi\int_0^\pi \frac{\sec^2xdx}{a^2+b^2\tan^2x} \,dx$

Now, solving by substitution method  (taking $b\tan x=t$)

I get 
[image]

(i have added the image because i was not able to type this correctly)

---

As the upper limit and lower limit on the  function are **zero**
So, answer should be zero.

But in the solution ( after getting this $2I=\pi\int_0^\pi \frac{dx}{a^2\cos^2x+b^2\sin^2x} \,dx$ )they have used the property

$$\int_0^2a f(x) \,dx= 2\left(\int_0^a f(x) \,dx\right)$$

Why they didn't ended the solution in the direction in which i did

**pardon for my mathjax errors**

Comment: HINT: Is the integral continuous over the bounds of the integral? You may have an improper integral.

Comment: One easy way to see why the answer should _not_ be zero is to observe that the integrand is positive and the area under it can't be zero.

Comment: @DavidG please explain what you are saying.. How is that integral isn't continous over the bounds of the integral?

Comment: Nothing is said about $a,b$.That's a problem if one is zero.

Comment: nothing is said in the original question about a,b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you substitute something that has to be increasing or decreasing throughout the interval and continuous also(otherwise you have to break the integra)l.
Here you have taken tan(x) which changes on π/2.

Comment: I got some idea

Comment: I wanna know more about this because things are still not clear...please give me some source reference

Comment: Here http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/SubstitutionRuleIndefinite.aspx